# typescript runs when using cmd but not when using bash

Tags: typescript, git-bash

When I run `tsc -v` or any other `tsc` command it is not running in the git bash terminal but runs fine on the command prompt.

I tried checking `npm path` in `bash`, but the `appdata/roaming/npm` path is already present in the `echo` path.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is best to cite the error messages. What exactly does "the command is not running" mean? Error message? Nothing at all?

Comment: when i run tsc -v, following message is displayed in git bash C:\Users\ved\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found